# make website link clickable and hide https://

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I have added some code to my website to show the user's website link (please see below) but the website link is not clickable so

1. I want to make the user website link clickable and highlighted.
2. I would like that if the user inputs `https://mywebsite.com` or `https://www.mywebiste.com` in that field it only show the website name like this `mywebsite.com`

Could you help me to achieve it?

```
        'field' => 'web', // Field name or ID.
    );
echo <a href="<?php echo $my_bio_excerpt; ?>" class="">click here</a>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP syntax is wrong in:

```
echo <a href="<?php echo $my_bio_excerpt; ?>" class="">click here</a>
```

Should be:

```
echo "<a href=\"$my_bio_excerpt\" class=\"\">click here</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add an `<a href></a>` to make it a link - see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Comment: Hi, thanks I have added this line but it is not working: echo <a href="<?php echo $my_bio_excerpt; ?>" class="">click here</a>

Comment: What html does it generate?

Comment: it says syntax error, unexpected '<' when trying to save the functions.php file

Comment: Well, I would need the whole file to analyze that. But maybe it says a bit more and also tells you where the syntax error is, exactly.

Comment: the code above is already the whole file. All works fine if I am not adding the extra echo line that I created. I am not a developer so I just try to guess how the code should look like. I have to rewrite this extra line maybe like this to make the link clickable echo ''<a href="" rel="nofollow"></a> but have no clue how.

Comment: Can you update your question with the current attempt that gives you the syntax error?

Comment: I cannot add the code that I applied because it doesn't let me save it here too, it says code is wrong. In fact when you take the code of my question, I simply added at the second last code line this code echo ''<a href="" rel="nofollow"></a>

Comment: Am I correct, that `my_bio_excerpt` might only contain a link and not be the whole link? Then you should introduce a new function that does what you want.

Comment: For example using a regular expression to replace all links with <a href="uri">domain</a>:
`preg_replace("/\b(https?:\/\/([^\s]+))/", "<a href='$1'>$2</a>", $input);`

Comment: my_bio_excerpt is a Buddypress Profile Field. So the code above takes the content of this user profile field and displays it on the user header.